# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_384': Exec format error

Tags: gpu, nvidia

After installing nvidia drivers, ***nvidia-smi*** is throwing this error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_384': Exec format error
>
> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
> driver.
> Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

My device specs are as follows:

- Server with a Tesla M40
- Running on Ubuntu 16.04
- Kernel version Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64
- Driver: nvidia-384

Can someone please tell what might be the reason?

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. What is your operating system and what are the versions of nvidia and nvidia-smi?

Comment: Server with tesla M40 , OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64, nvidia-384 version.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. This question might be more suitable for askubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer (I already posted it under another problem) might not be useful to you since I'm lack of knowledge about your error stacks, but will post here in case that it could help.

I ran into a similar problem with nvidia-390 after installing some Ubuntu Kernel updates in March. I followed the instructions [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+bug/1750937/comments/57) and managed to solve the problem. In general, use the following steps:

1. If you cannot login to the desktop and fall into to the fail-loop, press `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1` to login into the command line mode.
2. Check if the if the version of gcc is outdated, if so, update it: `gcc --version`
3. If the gcc version is 5+, uninstall the nvidia driver first: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-390`
4. Purge the 4.4.0-116 kernel: sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic
5. Reinstall the kernel: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-signed-generic`
6. Reinstall the nvidia-390: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`
7. Check if the problem is solved by `modinfo nvidia-387 -k 4.4.0-116-generic | grep vermagic`, make sure **retpoline** shows up this time
8. Reboot: `sudo reboot`

Hope this works for you and other people who run into the same issue. The post in the forum saved my weekend.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43160359/1602555) perhaps updating to NVIDIA 367.57 driver will fix your problem. You might ask on Ubuntu forums.